# Cannot reach html templateUrl in Angular 1.6

Tags: html, angularjs, state

I'm creating a simple web application in angular 1.6

I create a state for the url "/" but it seems that angular cannot reach the file don´t know why.

Folder structure is this:

[image]

So the html load the app like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>paykey</title>
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!--  --> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp" >

        <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/codigo.service.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the app.js file that has the state is this one:

```
'use strict';

 angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider'
  ])
  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
      // .state('home')
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/quote-comps.html',
        controller: 'MainT',
        controllerAs: 'main'
      });
});
```

So debugging it seems that it passes through stateProvider line but the html does not show up. The only thing I see is the background blonde in css, no errors in console.

The quote-comps.html file is this:

```
   <div ng-controller="MainT" ng-init="init()" style="padding-top: 90px;


       padding-left: 20px;">

       <div class="bar bar-header disable-user-behavior" >
        <div class="header">
          <div class="row header-wrapper">
            <div class="header-content col text" ng-class="currentPage.title!=undefined ? 'text':''">
       <div ng-if="currentPage.title != undefined">

              </div>
        <img src="images/ICONOS/Logo_banorte_ICO/Logo_Banortexxxhdpi.png" class="bem_image">
               <h5 style="text-align: center; color: white; margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top: 0px; font-size: 12px;">Bienvenido</h5>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="header-bar" ng-if="currentPage.name.indexOf('login') < 0 &amp;&amp; currentPage.name.indexOf('activaToken') < 0 &amp;&amp; currentPage.name.indexOf('resynchronize-token') < 0">
            <div class="clear"></div> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    <div  style="    margin-top: 52px;
        background-color: #35282B;
        height: 450px;
        overflow: scroll;">
        <h5 style="text-align: center; color: white; font-size: 16px"><!--{{operacion.nombreBeneficario}}-->55 1007 0744</h5>
        <h5 style="text-align: center; color: white; ">Has recibido un pago Banorte Móvil por:</h5>
        <h3 style="text-align: center; color: white; ">$ {{operacion.importeOperacion}} {{operacion.divisa}}</h3>
        <p ng-show="finish" style="text-align: center; font-style: bold; color: white;" ><span>¿Qué deseas hacer?</span></p>

    <img ng-show="finish2" class="amount-header ss2" src="../images/ICONOS/Exito_ICO/Exitohdpi.png" >

    <p ng-show="finish2" class="amount-header textBox4">¡El deposito fue exitoso!
                    </p>


        <div ng-show="finish" class="comparison-box" ng-class="{'comparison-box-open' : arrowUp}">
            <div class="comparison-header-container" ng-click="openMore('first')">
                <span>  <img style="width: 30px; display:inline;" src="../images/ICONOS/Depositarlo_ICO/Depositarlo.svg">  </img></span>
                <span class="comparison-header comboBox">Depositarlo</span>
                <img class="arrow" src="images/down_arrow.svg" ng-class="{'rotate180' : arrowUp, 'rotate360' : !arrowUp}">
                <!-- <img style="float: right; padding-right: 10px; width: 30px; margin-top: 4px; display: none;" src="images/up_arrow.svg"> -->
            </div>
            <div class="amounts-container">
                <div>
                    <p style="display: inline;" class="amount-header textBox" ng-class="{'show' : arrowUp && container, 'hide' : !arrowUp}">Ingresa:</p>
                    <input style="display: inline; text-align: center" class="amount-header inputIngresa" ng-class="{'show' : arrowUp && container, 'hide' : !arrowUp}" placeholder="Cuenta banorte, tarjeta o CLABE">
                </div>
                <span class="comboBox2"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="amounts-container">
                <div>
                    <p style="display: inline;" class="amount-header textBox" ng-class="{'show' : arrowUp && container, 'hide' : !arrowUp}">Banco:</p>
                    <input style="display: inline; text-align: center" class="amount-header inputIngresa" ng-class="{'show' : arrowUp && container, 'hide' : !arrowUp}" placeholder="Cuenta banorte, tarjeta o CLABE">
                </div>
                <span class="comboBox2"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="wizard-full">
                <!--<a href="#/form1"><button class="btn btn-primary btnSeg seg"> Depositar </button></a> -->
            </div>
            <button class="btn cus2" type="submit" ng-click="cancel()">Depositar</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="finish" class="comparison-box seg" ng-class="{'comparison-box-open' : arrowUp2}" style="">
            <div class="comparison-header-container" ng-click="openMore('second')">
                <span>  <img style="width: 30px; display:inline;" src="../images/ICONOS/Depositarlo_ICO/Depositarlo.svg">  </img></span>
                <span class="comparison-header comboBox">Cobrarlo en un cajero</span>
                <img class="arrow" src="images/down_arrow.svg" ng-class="{'rotate180' : arrowUp2, 'rotate360' : !arrowUp2}" ng-click="restauraE()">
                <!-- <img style="float: right; padding-right: 10px; width: 30px; margin-top: 4px; display: none;" src="images/up_arrow.svg"> -->
            </div>
            <div class="amounts-container">
                <div>
                    <p ng-show="mostrarQuieres" class="amount-header textBox" ng-class="{'show' : arrowUp2 && container, 'hide' : !arrowUp2}">¿Quieres generar tu código de referencia para retirar el efectivo en cajero automático?
                    </p>
                    <span>
          <img ng-show="mostrarAcude" class="amount-header ss1" src="../images/ICONOS/Exito_ICO/Exitohdpi.png" >
          </span>
                    <div ng-show="mostrarAcude" class="amount-header textbox2" ng-class="{'show' : arrowUp2 && container, 'hide' : !arrowUp2}">Acude a cualquier cajero Banorte, selecciona la opcion retiro de efectivo y captura o escanea este código para retirar tu efectivo
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="wizard-full">
                <!--<button class="btn btn-primary btnSeg2 seg" ng-click="getCode()"> Generar referencia </button> -->
                 <button class="btn btn-primary mGenT" type="submit" ng-click="generarTrans()">Generar transferencia</button>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="mostrar">{{codigoBarras}}
                <io-barcode code="123" type="CODE128B"></io-barcode>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-show="mostrar" class="wizard-full">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mGenT" type="submit" ng-click="generarTrans()"> d </button>
        </div>

    </div>




      <div class="footer">
      "2017  Derechos reservados."</div>

      </div>
```

[image]

dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
"@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.11",
"angular": "^1.6.6",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"jquery": "^3.2.1"
```

},

Comment: do you see a 404 error on console?

Comment: you have not specified a `ui-view` directive to load the template into

Comment: nop, it actually loads all the js needed

Comment: the ui-view should be in the app.js?

Comment: ui-view is a directive which is to be attached to an element as an attribute to put the loaddd template into.

Comment: and you said that it is loading all the js, that's true beacause it is fetching the template but not putting it in your html code. The reason behind this i that it can not find an element to put into, and that's what a ui-view directive does.

Comment: ok,so I place  <div ui-view></div> in the html but this does not bring the html what modification should I made to make it works? thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the controller...

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
    .controller('MainT', MainT);
```

to

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('MainT', MainT);
```

and works... I really don't know why

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

It seems you need to change $state.Provider to something like the following:

```
 $stateProvider
  // .state('home')
  .state('main', {
    url: '/',
    views:{
    'quoteCompsView':{
    templateUrl: 'views/quote-comps.html',
    controller: 'MainT',
    controllerAs: 'main'
        }
    }
  });
```

Then in your html add:

```
<div ui-view="quoteCompsView"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change url:

```
.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    views:{
     'quoteCompsView':{
      templateUrl: '../views/quote-comps.html',// -------- Here
      controller: 'MainT',
      controllerAs: 'main'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding reference in your main index html file .
I dont see any controller reference on html page

Comment: Ng-controller is not what you are asking? Is in quote-comps.html